# Find the maximum distance in between a given pair of nodes in graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

There are N nodes connected by N-1 edges. The weight of each edge is 1 and it's possible to reach any node from any other node.

We are given a subset of nodes. We need to pair(1 to 1 mapping) the subset of nodes and find the maximum distance possible after pairing.

```
For example:
N = 8 ( Number of nodes) 
subset of nodes = [2,4,5,6]

Graph: 

   7
   |
6--1--2--8 
   | 
   3--4
   | 
   5

Solution
Maximum distance: 
    Pairs
    (2,4) : 2-1-3-4 => distance 3 
    (6,5) : 6-1-3-5 => distance 3 
    max distance = 3+3 = 6
    It's possible to form other pairs but max distance will always comes out to 6.
```

How to calculate max distance?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. You may want to try looking on the Computer Science Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 1):

For the first find the centroid of the tree.
Next perform the following operations for each pair of vertices:
Find the distance between vertices and the centroid of the tree. The sum of these values is the maximum distance between the vertices.

Comment: I don't think that is true. Imagine the path-graph with 101 vertices labeled 0, 1, ..., 99, 100; with an edge between i,i+1 for every i. Consider the subset {99, 100}. The centroid of the tree is vertex 50; and the sum of values you suggest is (99-50)+(100-50) = 99. But the maximum distance is 1.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as there are `n` nodes, and `n-1` edges always connecting them, this must be a tree.

Let's say, length of subset, `k`.

The obvious approach is to run bfs for all the `k` nodes, it will give you all the distances from the nodes from the subset.

Then, we can do a nested loop (`k^2`) to find which pair has the largest distance.

Or, we can keep a `max_distance` variable, and update the max_distance while running the bfs, it will get rid of the extra `k^2` term.

We can further optimize this using an LCA. Once we select a root and have the LCAs, we can find any distance pair easily by, `d(node1, node2) = d(node1) + d(node2) - 2 x lca(node1, node2)`